# Weird White lines in Android Launcher?

Tags: android, user-interface, launcher

I'm currently programming and I noticed that there are strange white lines around the app in the Android Launcher. With other apps, everything is normal. Can someone help me how to remove them?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/954Kc.png)

Comment: Could you please highlight the lines you are on about within the screenshot, with an arrow or red box or something?

Answer (score 0):

Is that an actual image?

So this was a problem for us a while back. The result of the investigation ended with this blog post.

https://blog.jakelee.co.uk/avoiding-a-1-pixel-line-on-zeplin-exports-or-why-density-matters/

(Thanks Jake)